# Not able to load image on the html page

Tags: html, django, django-templates

I am making a project in django. I am able to implement html pages but not able to show images from that page.

```
<img src= "home/ashish/PycharmProjects/django/webapp/family/static/images/error-img.png" />
```

it is showing error as

```
Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html
```

when I hit the url,Request URL:http://127.0.0.1:8002/home/ashish/PycharmProjects/django_webapp/family/static/images/error-img.png

While if i make a src to online image it works fine.

setting.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/' # You may find this is already defined as such.
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
STATIC_PATH,)
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

And all the images are inside app/static/images.

Thanks

Comment: thats not how you load your static files. show your urls.py file

Comment: `from django.conf.urls import url,include`
 `from django.contrib import admin`
  `from views import *`

`urlpatterns = [ `
 `url(r'^setinfo', setdata, name='setdata'),`
 `url(r'^getdata', getdata, name='submitData'),`
 `url(r'^', not_found, name='not_found'),`

]

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined static file URLconf in your urls.py file. You can define them for development server use, like this:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
...
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

And then you can view your static files at:

`http://127.0.0.1:8002/static/images/error-img.png`

See: Django docs on [Managing static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/)